# Distances of disjoint Subsets

Tags: general-topology

Let : $ M={ \Bbb R  }^{ n }\ \quad A,B\subseteq M \quad A\cap B=\emptyset  $

and $\text{dist}(A,B):=\inf{ \left\{ \| x-y\| \; :\; x\in A,y \in B \right\}  }\\ $

be the distance between any two points in $A$ and $B$.

Is the $\mathrm{dist}(A,B)>0$ in all cases if:

1.) $A$, $B$ are open sets?

2.) $A$, $B$ are closed sets?

I can think of a few counter-examples to show that both statements are false but I don't really understand the concept yet.

e.g the Intervals $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ their intersection is empty but wouldn't there be a minimum distance between the first element of $A$ to the first element of $B$? Like the distance from $\mathrm{dist}(-0.1 , 0.1)$.

For the second statement, one could use $A=\{\text{natural numbers}\}$ and $B=\{ n- 1/n\}$, but there is still the same problem as it is in the first example.

And how could I prove those statements in a formal way without using counterexamples?.

Thanks for Tips and Help.

Comment: If you don't know the MathJax keyword for a symbol you can visit detexify.kirelabs.org, for example.

Comment: B as you defined it, a single element, has the distance of 1/n from A were A the set of natural numbers and n a positive integer. A as you defined it is loose, ambiguous use of the notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right when you say both statements or **false**.

When you say "*how could I prove those statements in a formal way without using counterexamples?*", remember that a false statement only needs a counter-example to be proved false. So a counter-example **is** a formal proof.

So:

- For the first one, take $A=(-1,0)^n$ and $B=(0,1)^n$ like you did which are subsets of $\mathbb R^n$. Then you can consider a sequence of points of $A$ and $B$ which get as close as each other as you want, which will prove that $d(A,B)=0$.
- For the second one, the idea is to take non-bounded subset. Take for instance in $\mathbb R^2$ (to simplify the idea):

$$A=\{(x,y),\ y\geqslant e^x\}$$

and

$$B=\{(x,y),\ y\leqslant -e^x\}.$$

See how you can conduct the same reasoning as before to show that $d(A,B)=0$. Take for instance

$$\begin{cases} a_n=(-n,e^{-n})\in A \\ b_n=(-n,-e^{-n})\in B\end{cases}$$

and you have $$d(a_n,b_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.$$

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, i get it now if something gets infinetly close to each other its distance always becomes zero. Could I use something like this as sequence $\lim _{ { x }_{ n }\rightarrow { x }_{ 0 } }{ |{ x }_{ n }-{ x }_{ 0 }| } $ for ${ x }_{ n }\quad \in \quad A$ and than the same for Elements in B?

Comment: In your first example $A$ and $B$ are neither open nor closed.

Comment: tiny last question, on your counterexample where does those sets get close to each other? aren't there no elements between e^x and - e^x on the y-axis?

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek You are right, thank you for the correction, I edited.

Comment: thanks for your effort, appreciate it!